# How to run a module on NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am quite new to NodeJS. At the moment, the server code is as below:

//app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
console.log("Listening on port 8080");
```

I have the following code that I am interested to run on server:

//strava.js

```
var strava = require('node-strava-v3');

strava.streams.activity({'id':444215395, 'types':'heartrate'}, function(err, payload){
    if(!err){
        console.log(payload);
    }
    else{
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

(For now I have hardcoded the data in the parameter)

#### Questions

1. How do I run Strava when the server is started?
2. How do I make payload available for the client?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in `app.js` add:

```
var strava = require('./strava.js');
```

In `strava.js` add to the end of file:

```
module.exports = strava;
```

To show output to the user you should take a look at [express requests](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app):

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

So, basically, you need to return data from strava.

If the data comes regularly, [sockets](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/) will do the job.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I will need to investigate sockets.